# Powershell long text Indentation/padding

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to indent a long string in a write-host.
While it trivial to .PadLeft() or prepend spaces in writing a short string, the same isn't true for a long one, as as soon as the cursor is at the last column of the string, it will continue from column 0 of the next row, e.g.:

```
"{0}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." -f $(" " * 5)
```

will show up as

```
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq
ua.
```

but what if I want it to obtain:

```
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
       sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore mag
       na aliqua.
```

?

Is there a way to accomplish this?
many thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to split the string up yourself based on the width of the console, and then pad the string and display:

```
$consoleWidth = $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width
$desiredIndent = 5  # spaces
$chunkSize = $consoleWidth - $desiredIndent

$bigString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. '*10

[RegEx]::Matches($bigString, ".{$chunkSize}|.+").Groups.Value | ForEach-Object {
    ' '*$desiredIndent + $_
}
```

Comment: works pretty well, but gets 'fooled' by strings containing CRs and LFs, which do 'reset' the string to Column 0. I've tried splitting by [.\s\S]{splitvalue} but it's not working the way I expect.. I'm surely missing something else...

Comment: also non-work characters seem to 'trick' it, such as quotes, double quotes, slashes etc..

Comment: `[RegEx]::Matches($_.InnerText , "\r\n|.{$chunkSize}|.+").Groups.Value | ForEach-Object {`                                
 

    did the trick. Basically, I'm splitting by CRLF first, THEN by chunk    size. Many thanks @briantist!!

Comment: @Aldo nice! I figured there'd be something I didn't account for